# Is it Possible to turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults with castle windsor fluent api?

Tags: castle-windsor, servicebehavior, wcffacility

I am getting this exception.

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.
>   For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from [ServiceBehaviorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.aspx)
>   or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in
>   order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on
>   tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and
>   inspect the server trace logs.

I want to add this configuration with fluent api

```
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="metadataAndDebugEnabled">
    <serviceDebug
      includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"
    />
    <serviceMetadata
      httpGetEnabled="true"
      httpGetUrl=""
    />
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Is there a way for it? Here is my current configuration ...

```
Container.Register(
    AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("My.Server.Services")
        .Pick().If(type => type.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsDefined(typeof(ServiceContractAttribute), true)))
        .Configure(configurer => configurer.Named(configurer.Implementation.Name)
            .LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation()
            .AsWcfService(
                new DefaultServiceModel()
                    .AddEndpoints(
                        WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new NetTcpBinding { PortSharingEnabled = true }).At(string.Format("net.tcp://localhost:6969/{0}", configurer.Implementation.Name)),
                        WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new NetNamedPipeBinding()).At(string.Format("net.pipe://localhost/{0}", configurer.Implementation.Name)))
                    .PublishMetadata()
            )
        )
        .WithService.Select((type, baseTypes) => type.GetInterfaces().Where(i => i.IsDefined(typeof(ServiceContractAttribute), true))));
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK You could register an `IServiceBehavior` implementation with your specific options to container and WCF Integration facility will use that instance.